# Better way of building urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I have a route configured like this:

```
get "calendar/:year/:month" => "calendar#month", as: :calendar_month
```

To create links for "next" month and "previous" month, this is what you need to use in your template:

```
<%= link_to "Next", calendar_month_path(year: @date.next_month.year, month: @date.next_month.month) %>
```

or a bit simpler:

```
<%= link_to "Previous", calendar_month_path(@date.prev_month.year, @date.prev_month.month) %>
```

Both feel a bit verbose.

Is there any way to take advantage of that the `@date.prev_month`/`@date.next_month` return an object (`Date`) that has methods which respond to defined in route params (`:year`, `:month`)?

Something similar to:

```
<%= link_to "Previous", calendar_month_path(@date.prev_month) %>
```

Would be an ideal solution, but it doesn't work.

How do you deal with similar situations?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add a method in your helpers to convert the date to a `calendar_month_path`:

```
def path_for_date(d)
  calendar_month_path(d.year, d.month)
end
```

Which means your links are:

```
link_to("Previous", path_for_date(@date.prev_month)
link_to("Next", path_for_date(@date.next_month)
```

Depending on your other routes you may want to name it a bit better than I have but you get the idea.